# Module compiled with Swift 2.3 cannot be imported in Swift 3.0

Tags: facebook, swift3, xcode8, swift2

i add Facebook SDK (Swift) to my project.
And now i update Xcode 8 and Swift 3.
I have error in build time

```
Module compiled with Swift 2.3 cannot be imported in Swift 3.0
```

It is very strange that is not supported.
Has anyone had similar problems?

Comment: Did you check if there is a newer Facebook SDK for Xcode 8 available?

Comment: yes, i check it and i do `carthage update`

Answer (score 11):

Remember to set `Use Legacy Swift Language Version` to `YES` for your project target

You are building your project in 2.3 and not in 3.0

Comment: I have the same exact error for a different module, `SinchVerification-Swift`. Updating legacy does not help. I already did `pod update` and got the latest. Is there a workaround?

Comment: hi, Use Legacy not work for me to. But i try `carthage update` this not work too. I use Carthage for dependencies.

Comment: As @subjective_c, Facebook will release the version for swift 2.3 very soon. Personally, this bug appear with `ObjectMapper` and to set the flag `Use Legacy Swift Language Version` to `YES` for for me...

Answer (score 2):

Have in mind that if you want to use Swift 3 as your main project's language you have to use pods that are either Swift 3, or Swift 2.2-. If you try to use a Swift 2.3 project, they will not compile (as in the error you describe).

So the best thing to do is to use either Swift 3 pods, or Swift 2 (2.1 or 2.2) pods and select Use Legacy SLV for that specific pod (in 'Pods' build setting for the specific target you want to use).

Answer (score 0):

Currently the Facebook SDK does [not yet](https://github.com/facebookarchive/facebook-swift-sdk/issues/26) support projects written in Swift 3.0.

There are a couple of [issues](https://github.com/facebookarchive/facebook-swift-sdk/issues/56) you can subscribe to on their Github for updates.

You'll have to use Swift 2.3 for now.  Facebook said it was planning to release an update soon after the GM was released, which has already happened, so it will probably come within the next few weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove all files under  `/tmp/Build/Products/...` and `/tmp/Build/Intermediates/...` and Build again.

Answer (score 0):

This maybe a little late but changing the settings to\fro Yes and No didn't help me but just clearing my derived data from the simulators just made everything work.