# Import Alamofire- "module compiled with swift 2.3 cannot be imported in swift 3.0.1"

Tags: ios, swift3, alamofire, swift2

I have been setting up a app in local... I got a error while trying to run the app in my iphone device. I got this error ,

"module compiled with swift 2.3 cannot be imported in swift 3.0.1" in the below step.

"import alamofire"

I have been tried other solutions provided by different sites. I'm unable to resolve this issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39484678/module-compiled-with-swift-2-3-cannot-be-imported-in-swift-3-0?rq=1

Comment: I have been used all the methods given in that site multiple of times. Nothing works for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Module compiled with Swift 2.3 cannot be imported in Swift 3.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39484678/module-compiled-with-swift-2-3-cannot-be-imported-in-swift-3-0)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40425598/1568889 addresses your exact problem.

Comment: Sorry to be like this.. Not working...

Comment: The point of the linked answer was that the combination you are using is not going to work. Using a recent version of Alamofire should help (at least version 4 if I remember correctly).